# How do I move my ServiceStack API from HTTP to HTTPS selectively

Tags: ssl, mono, servicestack

I followed the tutorial [deploy and run Service Stack application on Ubuntu Linux](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/mono-server-config) and I got my API quickly up and running. So far it's all *plain-text* though. I'd like to secure the API with SSL, especially the service receiving username and password, but maybe everything.

I'm using the regular CredentialsAuthProvider together with JwtAuthProvider at the moment, if it's relevant. Using a 3rd party OAuth2/OpenID Connect would solve the login problem, but not securing the remaining contents.

Also wonder how to selectively choose which services require SSL.

The stack is: mono, nginx and HyperFastCGI (and C# ServiceStack)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to [configure SSL on nginx](http://manual.seafile.com/deploy/https_with_nginx.html), i.e. your external-facing Web Server. What ASP.NET Web framework you're using is irrelevant as SSL will be terminated at nginx and any downstream Web Applications will still be receiving plain-text requests.

Comment: Thanks, and what about selecting which services/URIs require TLS? Is there an attribute for that in SS? So I can make sure e.g. the /auth/login path always gets encrypted credentials.

Comment: @specimen you can use the [\[EnsureHttps\] attribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/EnsureHttpsAttribute.cs).